# ImportError Numpy Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pycharm, anaconda

Работаю в PyCharm (Anaconda) необходимо работать с pandas, для этого требуется Numpy.

Установил с помощью команды `conda install -c anaconda numpy`. Все скачалось, но при запуске проекта выкидывает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/aquapolis.py", line 9, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

Comment: Попробуйте импортировать модуль из iPython, не используя PyCharm. Ошибка воспроизводится?

Comment: запустил через cmd, пишет туже ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил переустановкой anaconda и установкой Numpy через pip

Answer (score 2):

Я бы в вашем случае:

1. удалил Anaconda (`Uninstall-Anaconda3.exe`)
2. [установил Anaconda по новой](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows.html)
3. [создал бы несколько виртуальных окружений](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands)

   ```
   conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda
   conda create -n ml python=3.6 anaconda pandas
   ```
4. создаем ярлык для `iPython` из созданного виртуального оукружения (`C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ml\Scripts\ipython.exe`) и пользуемся данным `iPython` или настраиваем другой IDE

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит о том, что загрузка numpy зашла криво. Два варианта развития, как я вижу: переустановить библиотеку, либо с помощью git, очистить рекурсивно рабочее дерево (git-clean - Remove untracked files from the working tree), начиная с текущего каталога.

Comment: а в anaconda он с помощью git ставится?

Comment: просто удаление библиотеки и переустановка не помогает

Answer (score 0):

`File --> Settings --> Project: %ProjectName% --> Project Interpreter`.
Тут ищешь нужную библиотеку, если есть - удаляешь. Если нет - не удаляешь. После того как удалил(или не удалил), нажимаешь на плюсик справа. Ищешь, устанавливаешь.

Если я правильно понял про IDE, должно сработать.

Comment: Ошибка не пропала

Comment: попробуй вместо кучи импортов `from numpy import *`

Comment: Не помогло, к сожалению

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось решить данную проблему командой:

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```